# discord.js give role when react - no reply error in the discord server

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I wanted do a discord bot, and wanted it to give a role when someone reacts with an emoji, but it doesn't responsed.
My code, for now, looks like this:

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => { //here the bot adds the reaction
    if (reaction.partial) {
        try {
            await reaction.fetch()
        } catch (error) {
            return console.error('error');
        }
    }

    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("server-id");
    const role = guild.roles.cache.get("role-id");
    const member = reaction.message.guild.member(user);

    if (reaction.message.id !== 'text-message-id') return;
    else if(reaction.emoji.name === "") {
        if (member.roles.cache.has(fem)) return;
        else
            member.roles.add(role)
    }
})
```

and

```js
client.on('messageReactionRemove', async (reaction, user) => { //here the bot removes the reaction
    if (reaction.partial) {
        try {
            await reaction.fetch()
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('error')
            return
        }
    }

    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("server-id");
    const role = guild.roles.cache.get("role-id")
    const member = reaction.message.guild.member(user)

    if (reaction.message.id !== 'text message id') return 
   else if (reaction.emoji.name === "") {
       if (member.roles.cache.has(fem))
           member.roles.remove(role)
    }
});
```

1. I don't know what happened, but I thing has a version error (of
   discord.js) Someone can help me?
2. I wanted to a RPG server, when the player reacts to a emoji, a role
   of Wizard or Warrior is add...

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure if it will fix your error, but here's a few things you should apply to your code:

#### Make sure you enabled [`partials`](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/partials.html) in your `startup file`:

```js
const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'] });
```

#### Check if `user` is `partial`:

```js
if(user.partial) await user.fetch();
```

#### Restructure your `try block`:

```js
try {
   if(reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
   if(user.partial) await user.fetch();
}
```

#### [`Await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) the `role` to be added:

```js
if (reaction.message.id !== 'text-message-id') return;
    else if(reaction.emoji.name === "") {
        if (member.roles.cache.has(fem)) return;
        else await member.roles.add(role);
    }
```

You have to `await` this, because [`roles.add()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add) returns a [`promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

---

#### Also...

if you're planning to add some more `messages / reactions` you **can** use a [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) for this.

##### Example:

```js
// Listen for messages
switch(reaction.message.id) {
   case 'your message id':
      if(reaction.emoji.name === '') {
          // Your code, if the user reacted with 
      }
      break;
   case 'another message id':
      // if you want to listen for multiple reactions, you can add a switch for that
      // too
      switch(reaction.emoji.name) {
         case '':
            // your code if user reacted with 
            break;
         case '❌':
            // your code if user reacted with ❌
            break;
         default:
            break;
      }
   default:
      break;
}
```

##### Note:

Of course you don't have to use a `switch / switches` because for some people it's a bit confusing / not clean. You can manage this with `if / if else` statements too, but if this is getting more and more I'd recommend using a `switch`

---

The rest of your code looks fine, so I hope this will fix your problem :)

*You can also take a look at [my code](https://github.com/Toasty65/DiscordBot-Jarvis/blob/server/events/client/messageReactionAdd.js), handling this event*